# Replace a plot under the par() function of R

Tags: r, par

There should be an easy way to deal with this, but I don't know. I'm plotting multiple figures with the `par(mfrow=c(5,5))` subplot function of R (i.e. 25 figures). After plotting 10 figures say for example I've done something wrong with the 11th plot, now if I want to plot it again using `plot` function it takes the space for 12th subplot which means the whole subplot structure changes. I know that `par(new=TRUE)` would let me re-plotting on the top of the 11th figure, but what if the revised plot is so different that overlapping doesn't work? The idea is to erase the 11th figure and then plot it all over again. How about changing the 1st plot after plotting all 25 figures??

Comment: Base graphics are additive. That means once something is drawn, it cannot be undrawn unless you erase the entire device. I suppose you could draw white rectangle over the previous plot, but there's technically no "erasing" it.

Comment: Are you plotting 25 plots "by hand"? Aren't you using a script? Simply have a script that makes the 25 plots, starting with `par(new=TRUE)`, and then you can re-run the script ad libitum until you have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the `screen` family of functions, though I confess to not being an aficionado of them. As you would hope against, it is only to be used *exclusive* of `par(mfrow=c(5.5))` or even `layout(...)`.

Having said that, it is entirely possible to redraw over a screen. For instances:

```
split.screen(c(5,5))
for (scr in 1:25) {
    screen(scr)
    par(mar=rep(0,4)+0.1)
    plot(0)
}
screen(7)
par(bg='white') # necessary for some display types
erase.screen()
plot(2)
```

(This is certainly not a beautiful example, but it is functional.)

Notice the explicit setting of the background color (`bg`) to white; with some displays where transparency is assumed, not doing this will appear to have no affect (that is, `erase.screen()` will do nothing).

Having said that, there are many modern and near-modern graphing functions/libraries/packages that do things that this package does *not* support. I have not tested this with image-capturing mechanisms (such as sandwiching things in `png(file="...")` and `dev.off()`). **Caveat emptor**!